# uniformly convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} {{x^2+n} \over {n^2x^4+n^4+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis

$f_n(x)={{x^2+n} \over {n^2x^4+n^4+1}}$.

pointwise convergence: in all R because $|f_n(x)|\sim {{1} \over {n^3}}$ general term of a convergent series

uniformly convergence: I study it in $[0,+\infty)$ because $f_n(x)$ are even.

I proved to calculate sup$_R |f_n(x)|$ but is complicated.Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{x^2+n}{n^2x^4++n^4+1}$. Then
$$n^2x^4+n^4+1\ge n^2x^4+n^4=n^2(x^4+n^2).$$
Now, it is clear that for $|x|\ge1$, $x^2+n\le x^4+n^2$. Then, for $|x|\ge 1$, $0\le f_n(x)\le \frac{1}{n^2}$ and the Weierstrass Mayoration Test do the job.

For $|x|\le 1$, $0\le f_n(x)\le \frac{1+n}{n^4}$ and again Weierstrass Mayoration Tests guarantees the uniform convergence.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $x^2 \leq n$, then $|f_n(x)| \leq \frac{2n}{n^4+1} \leq 2n^{-3}$. 
If $x^2 > n$, $|f_n(x)| \leq \frac{2x^2}{n^2x^4} \leq 2n^{-3}$.